# How to print for each primary key all the foreign keys column related to it?

Tags: php, sql

I want  to  solve a PHP issue

1. I have a db with 2 tables:
   first one is "document":

   ```
              id  |    title       |                                   
         ================================
              1   |    equations    | 
              2   |    great        |  
              3   |    painting     |
   ```

second one is "pic":

```
          id   |   doc_id        |   description
    ===============================================
           1   |    1            |  "mathematics"
           2   |    1            |  "physic"
           3   |    2            |  "literature"
           4   |    2            |  "art"
```

2. the "doc_id" is a foreign key, related to  the id of the table "document"

3. this is my question: I'm trying to print for each title, all the descriptions related to it, example:

   ```
     for the title "equations" , the foreign key related to it, is "doc_id =1"
     which means for "equations" I will  print "mathematics" and "physic"
   ```

the final table printed using PHP and SQL, on my browser, should be:

```
             |   title       |   description
    ===============================================
             | equations     |  mathematics, physic
             | great         |   literature , art 
             | painting      |
```

Here's my code:

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "root";
$dbname = "doc-pic";
// Create connection
$conn =  mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
$sql = "SELECT * FROM pic LEFT JOIN document ON pic.doc_id=document.id";
                   $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
$sql1 = "SELECT title from document";
                  $result1 = mysqli_query($conn, $sql1);
?>
           <table>    
           <?php
 if (mysqli_num_rows($result1) > 0)
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result1)){?>
            <tr>
            <td><?php echo $row["title"]; ?></td>
            </tr>
            <?php  if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0 )
                     while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
                     ?>
                     <tr>
                     <td><?php echo $row["doc_id"]; ?></td>
                     <td><?php echo $row["description"]; ?></td>
                     </td>
                     </tr>
                     </td>
           <?php }

 } ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `left join` and aggregation:

```
select d.*,
       group_concat(p.description order by p.id) as full_description
from documents d left join
     pic p
     on p.doc_id = d.id
group by d.id;
```

Note that this uses `group by d.id` along with `select d.*`.  This works because `d.id` is (presumably) the primary key of `documents`.